# Отправка данных в Firebase(RealTime) не успевай пройти до выполнения следующих действий

Tags: java, android-studio, firebase, synchronized

Отправляю данные в Firebase (Real Time DataBase) и после этого сразу выхожу из этого активити. Но иногда данные не успевают отправиться до очистки и выхода из активити. как подождать отправку или проверять отправилось ли??

```
 trainPush.child(SettingsConstants.DATA).setValue(data);
    trainPush.child(SettingsConstants.KPW).setValue(kpw);
    trainPush.child(SettingsConstants.TONNAGE).setValue(tonnage);
    trainPush.child(SettingsConstants.INTENCITY).setValue(intencity);
    trainPush.child(SettingsConstants.TIME_TRAIN).setValue(timeTrain);
    trainPush.child(SettingsConstants.COUNT_ALL_EXERCISE).setValue(countExercise);
    trainPush.child(SettingsConstants.MY_WEIGHT).setValue(weight);

    //________ тут нужно подождать отправку данных или проверить отправилось ли?

    Intent intentBack = new Intent();
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intentBack);
    intentBack.putExtra(SettingsConstants.END_THIS_TRAIN_INTENT, 1);
    ConstructorFirstPartActivity.training.clearfullExercise();
    ConstructorTwoPartActivity.nameTimeCardio.clear();
    finish();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй использовать [транзакции](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write?authuser=0#save_data_as_transactions) для этого.

```
private void onStarClicked(DatabaseReference postRef) {
    postRef.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
        @Override
        public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
            Post p = mutableData.getValue(Post.class);
            if (p == null) {
                return Transaction.success(mutableData);
            }

            if (p.stars.containsKey(getUid())) {
                // Unstar the post and remove self from stars
                p.starCount = p.starCount - 1;
                p.stars.remove(getUid());
            } else {
                // Star the post and add self to stars
                p.starCount = p.starCount + 1;
                p.stars.put(getUid(), true);
            }

            // Set value and report transaction success
            mutableData.setValue(p);
            return Transaction.success(mutableData);
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b,
                               DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // Transaction completed
            Log.d(TAG, "postTransaction:onComplete:" + databaseError);
        }
    });
}
```